# React Native Button: Fit to text layout

Tags: react-native, react-native-button

In the Button docs from React-Native [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button) it shows an image which says: `Fit to text layout`. That is what I am searching for because my button always has full width, but I want it to only be as wide as the text is. But neither in the docs nor in the button code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js) I can find something related to that a prop or how can it achieve. Somebody has an idea how to get it?

Comment: You would be better to create your own button component that does what you want. That way you have complete control over.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I wanted just a very quick solution as react-native offers this directly and wondered how to get that option because the docs show it. Maybe somebody else had discovered how to get that setting...

Comment: I don't think that is what the docs are saying. I think they are saying that you could use a *layout strategy* to get the buttons to fit to text. For that me it would mean wrapping the buttons in a view that has flexDirection of row, probably with a justifyContent set to space-between. Doing that should recreate the example in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making your own button with TouchableOpacity and Text.

For example this is my component I often use :

```
export default class RoundedButton extends React.Component<Props>{

  render(){
    const defStyles : StyleProp<ViewStyle> = [style.button, {
      backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor,
    }, this.props.style];
    if(this.props.shadow)
      defStyles.push(style.shadow);


    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        disabled={!this.props.onPress}
        onPress={() => {
          if(this.props.onPress)
            this.props.onPress();
        }}
        style={defStyles}
      >
        <Text style={{
          color: this.props.textColor,
          fontFamily: fonts.bold,
          fontSize: 16
        }}>{this.props.centerText}</Text>

      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

}
```

You can found the full gist here if you want : https://gist.github.com/Sangrene/176c1b87ad5b355e26b5c6aa80b96eae.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the prop `adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}` in your Text component.

> If you add a fontSize in the styles of the Text, it will override this prop and won't work.

Example

```
<View style={{widht: 100, height: 60}}>
   <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}>
     Your Text Here
   </Text>
</View>
```